# How is the Damage Roll Multiplier for Kinetic Knights Calculated in Pathfinder Kingmaker?

Tags: pathfinder-kingmaker

For example, some of my characters have damage rolls of 1d6+5, and my character (a Kinetic knight using a kinetic blade) has a damage roll of 4d6+7.

I am aware that 4d6+7 means that I roll my dice four times, add the result, and add it to 7, giving me an attack value anywhere between 11 (4+7) to 31 (24+7). I am also aware that some weapons have fixed damage roll multipliers (as shown on the Pathfinder Wiki).

However, I haven't found any sources explaining how exactly the damage multiplier is calculated for
my kinetic knight's kinetic blade. I have seen other people with damage roll multipliers of 10 (10d6+1, for example). The game doesn't really explain, and I have been trawling forums and the in-game encyclopedia in search of the exact formula, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for answering my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kinetic Knight's Kinetic Blade power states that it "deals your Kinetic Blast damage on each hit (applying any modifiers to your kinetic blast's damage as normal, but not your strength modifier.

The Kineticist's Kinetic Blast states that there are three different possible kinds of blasts: Physical, Energy, and Composite.

> Physical blasts are ranged attacks that deal an amount of damage equal to 1d6+1 + the kineticist's Constitution modifier, increasing by 1d6+1 for every 2 kineticist levels beyond 1st. Spell resistance doesn't apply against physical blasts.

> Energy blasts are ranged touch attacks that deal an amount of damage equal to 1d6 + 1/2 the kineticist's Constitution modifier, increasing by 1d6 for every 2 kineticist levels beyond 1st.

> Composite blasts combine elements to form a new blast. When a kineticist gains a new element through expanded element, she gains access to all composite blasts for which she qualifies. Most composite blasts are either physical or energy blasts, like simple blasts.

> Physical composite blasts deal an amount of damage equal to 2d6+2 + the kineticist's Constitution modifier, increasing by 2d6+2 for every 2 kineticist levels beyond 1st.

> Energy composite blasts deal an amount of damage equal to 2d6 + 1/2 the kineticist's Constitution modifier, increasing by 2d6 for every 2 kineticist levels beyond 1st.

Using your example damage, you are presumably a 7th level Kinetic Knight, dealing a base 1d6+1 and an additional 1d6+1 for each set of 2 levels above first (or you're a 3rd level knight using a compound blast).

Comment: Thank you! I feel like a fool for reading everything (encyclopedia, online articles), but not going back to the kinetic blade itself and checking the tooltip. I'll take a closer look at the in-game description :) Thanks again for putting up with my noob question!